# Using partition by and case when

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, window-functions

To summarize what I am trying to do:

I have a bunch of regions, which one contains a lot of products. I have have calculated the discount of each product, the avarege discount of the products (partitioned by region) and also they standard deviation (partitioned by region too).

Now, what I need is calculate a new avarage discount (again partitioned by regions) but considering only the products that ***discount < avg_discount + stddvev_discount***

```
select  product,
        discount,
        region,
--this is the line i want to add
        avg (case when discont < avg_discount + stddev_discount then discount) over(partition by region) end as new_discount*
from (
  select product,
         discount,
         region,
         avg(discount) over (partition by region) as avg_discount,
         stddev(discount) over (partition by region) as stddev_discount
  from base
)
```

What I want:

[image: what i want:]

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  And show the query you have written.

Answer (score 0):

I am a little unclear on what results you want.  For what you describe, aggregation seems sufficient for the final results.

In any case, the idea is to use a subquery or CTE. 
 Something like this:

```
select region, avg(discount)
from (select t.*,
             avg(discount) over (partition by region) as region_avg,
             stddev(discount) over (partition by region) as region_stddev
      from t
     ) t
where discount < region_avg + region_stdev
group by region;
```

EDIT:

You can adjust this to use window functions:

```
select t.*,
       avg(case when discount < region_avg + region_stdev then discount end) over (region) as new_avg
from (select t.*,
             avg(discount) over (partition by region) as region_avg,
             stddev(discount) over (partition by region) as region_stddev
      from t
     ) t;
```

Comment: I dont want to loose any data. All I need is calculate the new region avarage discount, but now using the criteria that only the discount values that are lower than the previous avg + standard deviation must be used in the calculation